# Primary Key not saving auto increment integer in light switch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a project in Microsoft Light Switch 2010.  I have created a 'New Data Screen' and designed it appropriately.  For the data, my primary key is the 'ID' field and it always starts off at 0 when I run my program.  The auto increment for the 'ID' field works only when I have that instance of the program running.  But if I wanted to save, exit debugging, and re-run the program in debug mode again, the 'ID' field starts back over at 0. The previous data entry I entered at 'ID' 0 is still saved and I cannot enter another entry unless I manually change the 'ID' to a new integer.

Is there a way to start off at the next integer when I run the program again?  Or will it always start off at 0 no matter what?

Comment: When you created your table, did you change anything on the Id column? By default Lightswitch uses this field to do exactly what you're describing you'd like, so I don't see why it wouldn't increment accordingly. If it's only one screen and one table, maybe recreating them may help if something has gone wild?

Comment: I did not change anything on the ID column.  It increments while the program is debugging but once I exit debugging and start it back up, it starts over again at 0.  It's only on the new data screen.

Comment: Are you using the intrinsic database or attaching to an existing database? That's very unusual behaviour.

Comment: I am using a Database I attached from SQL server.  I created new tables intrinsically through Light Switch and that seems to work just fine with all the Primary keys incrementing.  So I'm guessing when you attach a database it will not auto increment?

Comment: It would auto increment if the schema is set correctly. Can you add a screen shot of you LS table designer and of schema from you SQL database. I'd guess there has to be something wrong there somewhere.